# how to reload the Jqgrid after upload the file by click upload Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I **upload** a file by click **upload button**. It should **reload** my **jqgrid** and the new value should be on top in the grid, It is a scenario of my Task. What are the changes I need to do in Jquery?. I use **loadonce = False** but it is load the grid continuously. If I reload the entire page, I am getting value in the grid.

```
_initUploadedFilesGrid: function(optionsM, resData){
             $('table#viewUploadedFiles').trigger("reloadGrid");
             $("#tmp").data('options', optionsM);
             $('#viewUploadedFilesDiv table#viewUploadedFiles').cb({
                    datatype: 'json'
                    ,mtype: 'POST' 
                    ,url: optionsM.urls.getAllUploadedFiles
                    , jsonReader : {
                        root:"UploadedFiles",
                    }
                    ,colNames:  [
                                 'Vendor Id'
                                 ,'Import ID'
                                 ,'Imported Organization'
                                 ,'Source Authoring Tool'
                                 ,'Import Start Time'
                                 ,'Import Completed Time'
                                 ,'Status'
                                 ,'File Name'
                                 ,'File Type'
                                 ,'Content Area'
                                 ,'Course'
                                 ,'Band'
                                ]
                    ,colModel:  [
                                {name: 'VendorId'}
                                ,{name: 'ImportFileId'}
                                ,{name: 'organizationId'}
                                ,{name: 'sourceAuthoringTool'}
                                ,{name: 'importStartTime'}
                                ,{name: 'importCompletedTime'}
                                ,{name: 'status'}
                                ,{name: 'fileName'}
                                ,{name: 'fileType'}
                                ,{name: 'contentAreaId'}
                                ,{name: 'CourseId'}
                                ,{name: 'BandId'}
                                 ]
                    ,columnchoosercaption: optionsM.msgs.chooseColumns
                    ,height: 'auto'
                    ,width: 1150
                    ,pager: '#viewUploadedFilesGridPager'
                    ,sortname: 'qImportFileId'
                    ,sortorder: "desc",
                    //,loadonce: false,

                    onSelectRow: function(rowId, status){

                        var $grid = $('#viewUploadedFiles table[id=viewUploadedFiles]');
                        var row = $grid.getRowData(rowId);
                        $.cete.contentEditor._itemStatusDialog(row.ImportFileId);
                    },
             });
                $('#viewUploadedFiles table#viewUploadedFiles').jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('#gridviewUploadedFilesContainer').width());

            },
```

```
$('input:radio[name=gradeType]').click(function() {
          var selected = $('input:radio[name=gradeType]:checked').val();
          if (selected=="Course") {
              $('#BandSettingDiv').hide();
              $('#CourseSettingDiv').show();
              $('#CourseId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
              $('#BandId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
            }
          else{
                 $('#BandSettingDiv').show();
                 $('#CourseSettingDiv').hide();
                 $('#CourseId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
                 $('#BandId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
            }
        });
    me._initUploadedFilesGrid(options, "");

},
```

Comment: You posted the code fragment without enough descriptions. Where you use `_initUploadedFilesGrid`? What is `.cb` which you use in the same way as `.jqGrid`? Why you included `$('table#viewUploadedFiles').trigger("reloadGrid");` at the beginning of `_initUploadedFilesGrid`, Which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? You wrote "It should reload my jqgrid", but it seems that you have more as one grids. Which one you need to reload?

Comment: If I give .cb it will display only 1 - 10 values in grids and it get value from DB also 10 columns values. But If i give .scb it will display 1- 10 values in grid and it get entire value from DB. When the page get load itself this method execute.( _initUploadedFilesGrid)

Comment: Sorry, but you don't answered on the most questions which I asked. First of all **what is `.cb` method?**. It looks like `.jqGrid`, but you should define it before all. You main problem is: "it is load the grid continuously". Thus it's important **where** (in which context) you call `_initUploadedFilesGrid`. For example if you call `_initUploadedFilesGrid` inside of `reloadGrid` processing (for example inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`) then you will have recursion.

Comment: We customize the Jqgrid into (.cb and .scb) and it have more css and grid design kind of feature. Instead of (.jqGrid).

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork?** jqGrid have a lot of customization. I supposed that all your requirements could be solved by usage the standard way. Nevertheless I can't help you till you don't specify exactly how `.cb` and `.scb` looks like. The problem which you report seems to exist in *your custom `.cb`*. Thus if you want that somebody else help you then you should describe exactly what you do.

Comment: version: jqGrid  4.4.4

Comment: Sorry, but I strictly recommend you to upgrade the retro version 4.4.4 to more recent version. Currently there are no more jqGrid, which latest version was 4.7. There are two main forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the version 4.12.1, which I develop since the end of 2014 and provide under old MIT/GPL licenses and commercial version [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) in the version 5.0.2. You should choose which fork you want to use and to migrate to the latest version from the fork.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code changes...
you said, there is a upload button which is in a dialog box right. use your upload dialog box id instead of this $("#progressOfUpload") and 
It will work for sure!

```
$('input:radio[name=BandType]').click(function() {
          var selected = $('input:radio[name=BandType]:checked').val();
          if (selected=="gradeCourse") {
              $('#BandSettingDiv').hide();
              $('#CourseSettingDiv').sh
              $('#CourseId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
              $('#BandId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
            }
          else{
                 $('#BandSettingDiv').show();
                 $('#CourseSettingDiv').hide();
                 $('#CourseId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
                 $('#BandId option').eq(0).attr("selected",true);
            }
        });
        $("#progressOfUpload").off('dialogclose').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
            $('table#viewUploadedFiles').jqGrid('GridUnload');
            me._initUploadedFilesGrid(options, "");
        });
    me._initUploadedFilesGrid(options, "");

},
```

Comment: It working fine Krish. But while it getting reload it getting closed and reloading. What should I do for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems be very suspected. Especially the selectors like

```
$('table#viewUploadedFiles')
$('#viewUploadedFilesDiv table#viewUploadedFiles')
$('#viewUploadedFiles table[id=viewUploadedFiles]')
```

The usage of unknown method `.cb`, which have the same options like `.jqGrid` is suspected too.

I suppose that you create HTML markup with **id duplicates**, which is not allowed in HTML and can follow many problems. The values of `id` attribute on the page have to be unique.

Even if the `<table>` with `id` equal to `viewUploadedFiles` is unique, you should never use the selectors like `#viewUploadedFilesDiv table#viewUploadedFiles` or `table[id=viewUploadedFiles]`. DOM API hold the map (dictionary) object which allows to get DOM element by id very quickly. There are **native** DOM method [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp). If you use `$("#viewUploadedFiles")` then the method will be used by jQuery internally and the execution will be quickly. If you use *other selectors* like `table[id=viewUploadedFiles]` the execution will be slowly because `getElementById` can't be used. The selectors like `'#viewUploadedFilesDiv table#viewUploadedFiles'` will be slowly too because jQuery will first make `$("#viewUploadedFilesDiv")` using `getElementById` and then execute `.find("table#viewUploadedFiles")` on `$("#viewUploadedFilesDiv")`. It makes the execution slowly and should be used only if your HTML markup is buggy and you allows to have *multiple elements with the same id="viewUploadedFiles"*. jqGrid code uses id selector with the grid id (`$("#viewUploadedFilesDiv")`) internally. Thus it doesn't support usage on `<table>` which have id duplicates. As the result *another* grid could be reloaded and you could have recursive reloading of the parent grid.